# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: ienumerable

Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

This is my code below. I don't cant see why this is not working. I get this error above.

dgTimeSheets.DataSource = _DataViewSingleImport;

Comment: I suppose you are working in C# or VB.NET. Add tags for your question. Also I think that your problem is obvious: `_DataViewSingleImport` is not initialized.

Comment: Nah, if it isn't initialized the error would be about null data.

Comment: The issue is that it's a private variable and not a get or set property. Once I change it to a get or set property everything work just find. Could you explain why could not use a private variable instead?